# How to hide folders from URL using php or htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, directory

I have images and documents located after a series of folders like this:

```
http://domain.tld/library/data/info/history-of-america/hoa1.pdf
http://domain.tld/library/data/info/history-of-america/hoa2.pdf
http://domain.tld/library/data/info/50-moments-in-history/50mih.png
```

I have used php to redirect shorter links to these long URLs like so:

```
http://domain.tld/15
http://domain.tld/16
http://domain.tld/21
```

But because I am using the header redirect, when I click these short links they redirect to the files and display the long filepaths again.

How can I preserve the short links or at least get rid of the folders in the long links when the file is visible on the browser?

```
http://domain.tld/15
http://domain.tld/16
http://domain.tld/21

OR

http://domain.tld/hoa1.pdf
http://domain.tld/hoa2.pdf
http://domain.tld/50mih.png
```

Note I have hundreds of these files so manually inputting for each one is not scalable for me.

Thanks in advance. I've just been getting so much errors when trying other Q&A solutions so a clear path would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^15/?$ library/data/info/history-of-america/hoa1.pdf [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^16/?$ library/data/info/history-of-america/hoa2.pdf [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^21/?$ library/data/info/50-moments-in-history/50mih.png [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your .htaccess page

```
#url forwarded
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_.-]+)$ library/data/info/history-of-america/hoa1.pdf$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```